# Can not import flask app

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I have a structure like this:

```
flask_api
    api
        __init__.py
        tests
            test_base.py
    manage.py
```

In **init**.py:

```
def create_app():
    connexion_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='swagger/')
    connexion_app.add_api('output.yaml', resolver=RestyResolver('api'),  validate_responses=True)
    app = connexion_app.app

    CORS(app)
    app.register_blueprint(utils)
    ...
    return app
```

In manager.py:

```
from api import create_app

app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def test():
    print(app.root_path)
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover(
        'api/tests',
        pattern='test*.py'
    )
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)
    if result.wasSuccessful():
        return 0
    return 1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

and in test_base.py:

```
from flask_api import app
```

Now, when I run python menage.py test I get the error:

```
  File "/home/flask_api/api/tests/test_base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask_api import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_api
```

How can I import app into the test_base?

Comment: You should not. In your tests import again `from api import create_app` and there create your new app instance.

Comment: And then you can `self.app = create_app()` for readability.

Comment: You should add a file `flask_api/__init__.py`

Comment: @needtobe It works. You should post your comment as answer so I can upvote it and mark it as answer.

Comment: Of course, thanks.

Comment: Answer posted. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tests import again from `api import create_app` and there create your new app instance.

So simply:

```
from api import create_app
```

After all, for simplicity you can assign `self.app = create_app()`